# RMarkdown "Unequal factor levels: coercing to character...binding character and factor vector"

Tags: r, macos, data-binding, r-markdown

I have three dataframes, `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`. They each have columns `date`,`A`, `B`, `C`. I made sure that all the date columns in each of the dataframes were of the same class (Date), all the A columns in each of the dataframes were of the same class (factor), and the classes of the other two were integers. I used `ungroup()` to get rid of any grouping I had used in the dataframes.

So the dataframes look something like:

```
-    Date    |   A   | B | C
1 2020-01-01 | House | 1 | 2
2 2020-01-02 | House | 3 | 4
3 2020-01-03 | House | 5 | 6

-    Date    |   A   | B | C
1 2020-01-01 | Field | 1 | 2
2 2020-01-02 | Field | 3 | 4
3 2020-01-03 | Field | 5 | 6

-    Date    |   A   | B | C
1 2020-01-01 | Store | 1 | 2
2 2020-01-02 | Store | 3 | 4
3 2020-01-03 | Store | 5 | 6
```

Then I tried to use `new_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)` to append them into a single dataframe (new_df). No errors appear. I used `new_df$A <– as.factor(new_df$C=A)` to ensure that A was indeed a factor.

new_df looks something like:

```
-    Date    |   A   | B | C
1 2020-01-01 | House | 1 | 2
2 2020-01-02 | House | 3 | 4
3 2020-01-03 | House | 5 | 6
4 2020-01-01 | Field | 1 | 2
5 2020-01-02 | Field | 3 | 4
6 2020-01-03 | Field | 5 | 6
7 2020-01-01 | Store | 1 | 2
8 2020-01-02 | Store | 3 | 4
9 2020-01-03 | Store | 5 | 6
```

Then I made a ggplot with `graph <– ggplot(data = new_df, aes(x = B, y = C, group = A) + geom_line() + transition_reveal(date)`. No errors appear. I checked the plot data, and the data was of type double (S3: Date), factor, integer, and integer (as expected).

When I go to print the plot with `animate(graph, renderer=gifski_renderer("graph.gif")` by pressing 'run current chunk', the graph prints nicely and I can open the gif file.

However, when I press Knit, with an output to a pdf_document, the following error appears:

```
Error: Unsupported device In addition: Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector Execution halted.
```

The error is traced back to the line where I used the `animate()` function.

I'm not sure what the issue is because I can't spot where the unequal factors are, but it is preventing me from getting my desired output.

Any thoughts?

Comment: (FYI: inline code in SO questions only require a single backtick, not the triple-backticks you were using. Hope I save your pinky-finger some extra work with that knowledge :-)

Comment: (1) Have you done your testing in a new/fresh R environment? Sometimes rmarkdown docs reference a variable that exists in the global environment, where step-by-step testing will not run into problems. (2) You might verify that your library path (`.libPaths()`) is identical in your testing environment and when you knit.

Comment: You can't have animated gifs in a PDF document, that's why it's failing to knit. And those warning messages are expected when you're using `dplyr::bind_rows` with factors that don't have the same levels